# How to convert tree to threaded binary tree

Tags: delphi, pointers, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have a code for creating a binary tree and its recursive output. How to convert binary tree to threaded tree and print it iteratively?

```
type
  PAvl = ^TAvl;
  TAvl = record
           key: integer;
           left: PAvl;
           right: PAvl;
           isThreaded: boolean;
         end;

procedure create(var root: PAvl; digit: integer);
begin
  if root = nil then begin
    New(root);
    root^.key := digit;
    root^.left := nil;
    root^.right := nil;
  end
  else if root.key > digit then
    create(root.left, digit)
  else 
    create(root.right, digit);
end;

procedure Print(root: PNode; depth: integer = 0);
var 
  i: integer;
begin
  if root <> nil then
  begin
    Print(root^.right, depth + 1);
    for i:=1 to depth do 
      Write(#9);
    Writeln(root^.data);
    Print(root^.left, depth + 1);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Wikipedia has a pretty good explanation.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_binary_tree

Comment: The code is not real, just mixture from two sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is as simple and straight forward as you make it. (pun intended) You decide before hand which traversal method you prefer. Child first or self first. Then you do that traversal, setting up the links. Basically you then have both a tree and a linked list implemented.

The harder problem is keeping the beast balanced. Having a linked list and a count of nodes helps this quite a bit. Hint, I would use a recursive function to find the middle of the list, make that the new leaf node (or root if no nodes exist), then trim self out of a temporary left chain, and a temporary right chain. Call the function on each temporary chain to obtain child nodes.

For most implementations not involving search optimization you are going to want to point to parent rather than having nodes point to children. This allows for any n number of children for a given parent. You can make the child list a ragged array or linked list if you want. So in the end you will combine the search chain with other data structures to get your results.

Of course the other thing to ask yourself is does the implementation warrant keeping everything in memory. Lots of times you are far better off letting the database do the work if that is where it lives.

Best wishes. Good question.